# Alternative to goto-statement in this case?

Tags: c, clean-code, coding-style

Currently I am using gotos for closing handles and general cleanup if an error occurs.
Since I don't want to nest all the ifs and a function for cleanup would require a `return` besides the `cleanup();` call, I don't have any good ideas left.

The structure is like so:

```
if (condition1) {
   goto cleanup;
}

if (condition2) {
   goto cleanup;
}

if (condition3) {
   goto cleanup;
}

// do stuff only if all checks passed

cleanup:
CloseHandle(x);
CloseHandle(y);
// etc.
```

Comment: ...see also: [Is this a decent use-case for goto in C?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/154974/is-this-a-decent-use-case-for-goto-in-c)

Comment: Just use `goto`.  It makes the intent of the code clear and is cleaner than camouflaging the control flow by any misguided attempt to cheat around using the `goto` statement.  I really dislike the idea of blindly following “never do X” rules when X actually is the best (least bad) alternative in a given case.  This particular pattern (`goto cleanup;`) is actually quite idiomatic in C.

Comment: There was a [study](https://peerj.com/preprints/826v1/) (pre-print, not peer-reviewed) on the use of `goto` in C that concluded that this is the case where they're being used and that applications which cause spaghetti are relatively rare.

Comment: This is basically using `goto` to implement a custom control structure. Go recognized this for what it is - a control structure - and added the `defer` statement to cover this (valid) use-case.

Comment: @5gon12eder, not that I don't want to use goto, just my boss doesn't want me use it.

Answer (score 7):

The cleanup could be in an outer function, and then `return` can be used instead of `goto`:

```
void main_func() {
    /* Set-up goes here */
    handle x = ...;
    handle y = ...;
    void result = inner_func(x, y);

    /* Clean-up goes here */
    CloseHandle(x);
    CloseHandle(y);
}

void inner_func(x, y) {
    if (condition1) return;
    if (condition2) return;
    if (condition3) return;

    /* Do things here */
}
```

But `goto` for things like this isn't *that* bad, in my opinion.

Comment: ok, that could actually be a possibility.

Comment: The slight problem I have with this is the same that I have with manlio's third solution.

Comment: wouldn't this increase the coupling between the two part of the code?  Any coder calling `inner_func` would have to first open the files and then remember to close them. code reviews would be ineffective here to catch the problem.

Comment: @KinjalDixit: the function wouldn't be meant to be called from elsewhere. My C is too rusty to suggest how to handle that -- maybe start the name with an underscore, don't put it in the .h file, et cetera.

Comment: +1, this is the best solution. But I have to disagree in the last sentence: given a perfectly valid and readable alternative, `goto` _is_ that bad.

Comment: @Konamiman but it isn't as good as the goto solution, since you shouldn't call the other functions when one before failed.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich:  You're looking for `static` to make the function invisible to the outside.  A good compiler would take care of inlining it, which would result in the same code as a `goto` without the overhead of a function call.

Comment: Just a reminder, handle `x` may succeed while handle `y` may fail. Or vice versa. One will need to check the validity of each handle before calling `CloseHandle`. In situations where if `x` fails and one wants to bail out without trying to acquire `y`, one will still have to hand-code the "variable unwind" code - something C++ can automatically generate, but C programmers must write manually.

Answer (score 4):

In C a typical way to simplify error checking and avoid deep nested `if` is:

```
do
{
  if (condition1) break;

  /* 1. do something... */

  if (condition2) break;

  /* 2. do something else... */

  if (condition3) break;

  /* 3. do something else... */
} while(0);

/* Cleanup */
```

There are various opinion on this "idiom" (e.g. take a look at [Do you consider this technique “BAD”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243967/do-you-consider-this-technique-bad)).

Possibly you should add a comment on the `do` to make it clear to anyone what's happening.

You can often rewrite the code using a helper function and change the fake do-loop into:

```
void func(X *x, Y *y)
{
  if (condition1) return;

  /* 1. do something... */

  if (condition2) return;

  /* 2. do something else... */

  if (condition3) return;

  /* 3. do something else... */
}


/* ... */
X x;
Y y;

func(&x, &y);

/* Cleanup */
```

and it won't be considered a "bad practice" since it's more expected.

If you haven't the intermediate steps (`1.` and `2.`) this is probably enough:

```
int stop = condition1 || condition2 || condition3;

if (!stop)
{
  /* ... */
}

/* Cleanup */
```

Comment: Good idea, but this would require a function or goto for the things to be done if all checks passed.

Comment: @Benjoyo: that other stuff could go in the `/* do something else */` part, right? And what's wrong with putting the stuff in a function?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I would need to pass a ton of handles and so on. Also this isn't really such a good SoC that I would like to use a function.

Comment: Your third suggestion is an option, I didn't consider something like this because I didn't want to, if the first function fails, force the following ones to try their luck even if it's clear that they will fail.

Comment: The first idea abuses the while/break language feature, goto can be considered more explicit and cleaner in such a case.

Answer (score 4):

You could try saying what you mean:

```
if (!condition1
 && !condition2
 && !condition3 ) {

// do stuff only if all checks passed
}
CloseHandle(x);
CloseHandle(y);
// etc.
```

As various commenters have pointed out this is only readable/maintaibable if the condition tests are fairly simple where complex conditions are involved something like this is cleaner:-

```
if (doAble()) {
   // usefull work here
}
CloseHandle(x);
CloseHandle(y);

boolean doAble() {
  if (condition1) {
     return false;
  }
  if (condition2) {
     return false;
  }
  if (condition3) {
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

However if you need lots of local variables to evaluate the conditions this too can get messy.

Comment: Wow, saying what you mean is also simpler and clearer than the alternatives.  Who would have thunk it?

Comment: Maybe this is really a good option, since evaluation will stop if one condition is false, right?

Comment: Which also gets you a hard-to-reason about chain of negatives, nowhere to put any condition-specific logic or logging, and some free indentation. It's fine in the case shown, but IMO scales poorly as the number (or complexity) of conditions grows.

Comment: If the number or complexity of conditions grows, it should be broken into smaller pieces and separate functions.